# How to get innerHTML with Xpath javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I need to retrieve text from inner element. With php it so easy to use Xpath. how about in javascript? I need to retrieve from specific element with specific id too. the request under code below. Let say it doesnt problem with CORS. i installed chrome extension to solve CORS.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<script>


   fetch('https://alexistogel1.blogspot.com/2019/08/post-tak-penting.html')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (html) {
      var element = document.evaluate( "//div[@id='post-body-6034358444211110141']" ,document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
      console.log(element);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you forced to use XPath?

Comment: no, all solution is accept.

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument on `document.evaluate` be `html`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier i tried it too, it gives error **Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'**

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert your string to a `document`.
Now you can use the `document` to select the element inside it with the help of `getElementById`.

```
fetch('https://alexistogel1.blogspot.com/2019/08/post-tak-penting.html')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (text) {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        return parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    })
    .then(function (html) {
        var element = html.getElementById('post-body-6034358444211110141');
        console.log(element.innerHTML);
    });
```

Comment: i gives error like enum. then i change application/html to text/html to fix. but give other error when itry `console log(element.stringValue);`

Comment: `stringValue` is no property that `element` contains. You'll want to get the `innerHTML` property to get the values inside an element. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Xpath solution return undefined.

Comment: I've removed the XPath answer since it does not seem to work. `getElementById` is a native JavaScript function which is the more preferable way to select an element.